# Sources for new experimental limits on susy models?

Tags: supersymmetry, large-hadron-collider

I know the LHC people are publishing new limits every now and then, but as a non-expert in reading experimental papers (yet), I was wondering if there's a friendly website that collects and presents the limits in a readable and accessible way for non-experts?

Comment: If you are willing to be 6-12 months behind the leading edge you can read review papers and the state of the discipline talks given at major conferences.

Comment: There is fun and fairly clear rumors to be found in http://blog.vixra.org/ usually presented simply . Also I check often the experimentalist's blog http://www.science20.com/quantum_diaries_survivor for updates. And of course Lubos blog http://motls.blogspot.com/ where there are good articles on complex theories but also when experimental news break a good coverage .

Comment: Thanks Anna for the links, and I surely know Lubos's blog (who doesn't? :p). I usually prevent myself from visiting vixra because, at this stage, I fear I won't be able to tell if what I'm reading is trustable or not.

Comment: @dmckee I can do this, but it's always better to be up-to-date, hence my enquiry.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any such website. Aside from the arxiv, I usually look for new experimental results posted as publicly-available notes on the web, e.g. [here from CMS](http://cdsweb.cern.ch/collection/CMS%20Physics%20Analysis%20Summaries?ln=en) and [here from ATLAS](https://atlas.web.cern.ch/Atlas/GROUPS/PHYSICS/CONFNOTES/). But those are the experimental papers, not a digested form like you're asking about. They have gotten much better about presenting material in a useful way, though; for instance a recent ATLAS result includes [this plot](https://atlas.web.cern.ch/Atlas/GROUPS/PHYSICS/CONFNOTES/ATLAS-CONF-2012-058/fig_03d.png) on limits for a gluino decaying to a neutralino and a top/antitop pair. Last year, many of us in the theory community were spending a great deal of time simulating and re-interpreting experimental results to understand the limits on scenarios like this. Now they're usually right there in the paper.

I think the Higgs boson mass is by far the single most important constraint on supersymmetry to come from the LHC so far, although the direct searches matter too. The new possible gamma-ray line signal is another interesting development, and other new results from outside the LHC, like an update on the electron EDM, are going to come our way this year too. So there are a lot of developments to keep an eye on. Honestly, aside from monitoring the arxiv and the experimental websites, I think the best public source for "readable and accessible" updates may be Adam Falkowski's Resonaances blog.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the links and the blog. I'm still a novice with regards to reading experimental results and plots, but I certainly should learn how to get the info from the papers. Anyways, I also found this: https://twiki.cern.ch/twiki/bin/view/AtlasPublic/CombinedSummaryPlots which contains what I was particularly  looking for (the new limit on gluino)